# Android ButterKnife can't bind TabItem View

Tags: android, butterknife

I have a problem with ButterKnife. I have a TabLayout with multiple TabItems as child in my activity layout file. Under this TabLayout, I got a RecyclerView. I bind these views with ButterKnife. The binding of the RecyclerView works fine but for the TabItems, I get the following exception:

```
Required view 'ID_OF_MY_TAB_ITEM' with ID 2131296287 for field 'tabItem' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.
```

The views are not optional, so annotating it with @nullable and @optional is not a solution for me. The views are correctly set up in the layout file.

Anyone had a similar problem with TabItems and ButterKnife?